# Can decimal point number represent any value without alterations and rounding issues

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Am I right that [decimal floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) can represent any "finite-value" (not 1/3 situations) without any alterations so it doesn't have "non-representable" numbers like [0.1 in case of binary floating point](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) and can't accumulate a rounding error after any mathematical calculations? If so, how is it possible? I mean, AFAIK there's a precision limit for the DFP numbers anyway, so at one point they will be unable to store the "real" value and be forced to round it somehow.

But anyway -- does it have any "non-finite" numbers (I wonder is there any better term for such values) that can't be represented without any alterations (like the already mentioned 0.1 in case of binary floating point numbers)?

Comment: How could a finite state machine represent an infinity of things?

Comment: You should re-compose this question.  First you start off with the bad form of *"am I right..."*, which is a combination of assertion and question.  Then you ask for proof of your assertion!

Comment: It very much depends on the decimal floating point numbers. If they are multi-precision (there are also fixed precision decimal floating point numbers), they can represent *a lot*, but even they are not infinite. They can store any decimally representable value that fits in memory, though.

Comment: If you exclude all “1/3 situations” by definition, of course you don't have any of the troublesome 1/10-in-binary situations. What is your question?

Comment: Decimal floating point numbers can represent exactly every number with a sufficiently short decimal fraction representation. Binary floating point numbers can represent exactly every number with a sufficiently short binary fraction representation...

Answer (score 0):

What you've noticed is that there are some numbers, like 1/10, which are exactly representable with a finite number of digits in base-10, yet not in base-2... yet there seem to be no numbers which are representable with a finite number of digits in base-2 but not in base-10. That's true!

Where you go wrong is in thinking of that as a fundamental and important property of the numbers themselves. In reality, "representable with a finite number of digits in base-10", or in base-2, is not very important (other than to those two bases). If you're wondering what typifies them, here it is:

> A rational number a/b, where a and b are finite integers with no common factors, is representable with a finite number of digits in base-10 if and only if b is expressible as a power of 2 multiplied by a power of 5.

So 1/10 works. 7/16 works. 3/500 works. 83/625000 works. 1/3 doesn't work.

The equivalent property for base-2 is the same as for base-10 once you delete the words "multiplied by a power of 5". So 7/16 still works, but 1/10 doesn't. Base-10 is capable of expressing a wider range of rational numbers with a finite number of digits than base-2 (because it has all the prime factors that 2 has, and then some).

But again, this is not a fundamental property of the numbers outside the context of base-10. On another planet, which uses base-60, the aliens are laughing at us for not being able to express 1/3 with a finite number of digits.